# How to get Tshark Data in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, wireshark, tshark

I am trying to capture a simple command using subprocess and TShark.

```
import subprocess

tsharkCall = ["tshark", "-a", "duration:2", "-i", "2"]
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall,
                              bufsize=0,
                              executable="C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe",
                              shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print(tsharkProc.communicate()[1].decode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Capturing on 'Local Area Connection* 4'
tshark: Invalid capture filter "/c tshark -a duration:2 -i 2" for interface 'Local Area Connection* 8'.

That string isn't a valid capture filter (can't parse filter expression: syntax error).
See the User's Guide for a description of the capture filter syntax.
0 packets captured
```

Any ideas why? Thanks you very much ♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very easy fix change

```py
tsharkCall = ["tshark", "-a", "duration:2", "-i", "2"]
# to
tsharkCall = ["C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe", "-a", "duration:2", "-i", "2"]
# and
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall,
                              bufsize=0,
                              executable="C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe",
                              shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# to
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall,
                              bufsize=0,
                              shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is that you called tshark two times once with the command and other with kwarg `executable`

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it recently but you might want to look at pyshark.
It's a python wrapper around tshark.

https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark